# Exception catch for Heroku "Connection closed without response"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using heroku to run my application and set the timeout = 12s (using racktimeout), using unicorn, sometimes I am getting the H13 issue

```
2010-10-06T21:51:37-07:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" 
method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=17.17.17.17 dyno=web.1 connect=12610ms service=15882ms 
status=503 bytes=0
```

So this breaks in between the code execution, can we handle this in the exception anyway? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Set the timeout to 30 seconds. And examine if the problem will recur. This should help.

The documentation says:

> When a Unicorn web server is configured with a timeout shorter than 30s and a request has not been processed by a worker before the timeout happens.
> In this case, Unicorn closes the connection before any data is written, resulting in an H13.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response

Comment: Yeah but is it good to set the timeout as 30s, one main thing is can I handle this exception anyway  even if I put 12 seconds?